# Rollup can't compile/transform all my less, sass and css files with PostCSS (Sapper framework)

Tags: less, svelte, rollup, postcss, sapper

[This](https://github.com/GitGangGuy/rollup-sapper-issue)  is the repo containing the faulty `rollup.config.js` file. Somehow, it won't compile my LESS files with the correct parser, hence the error I'm getting:

```
You tried to parse Less with the standard CSS parser; try again with the postcss-less parser
```

when I start my [sapper](https://sapper.svelte.dev) build process with `yarn dev` (you can also use npm). I've already tried to pass the `postcss-less` parser with the `parser` argument to the `postcss()` function exposed by `rollup-plugin-postcss`, but that didn't change anything. It is also quite difficult to tell where the error exactly happened, which is why I've already setup a little `rollupDebugger` script that dumps all stylesheets into the `dumps` directory after each change so you can follow along (and hopefully find the bug). I tried a few other ways to debug this as well (`postcss-reporter`, `postcss-debugger`...), but they didn't prove to be helpful at all.
This is why I'm turning to the StackOverflow community now. I hope there are some smarter minds out there that can wrap their heads around rollup logic ;)
I appreciate feedback, everything can help; thanks a lot!
My goal is to have the

- sass files parsed, prefixed (`autoprefixer`) and minimized (`cssnano`) in production for the svelte material UI library
- less files parsed, prefixed and minimized as well
- css/less/sass in components processed, parsed, prefixed and minimized in the same manner
- Every stylesheet (regardless of preprocessor) should be able to be included over import statements or over `<style src=x>` tags
- all unused css should be purged in production

Comment: There are multiple issues in the repo you've linked. My advice would be to restart from scratch. Just `yarn add -D rollup-plugin-postcss less node-sass` in a raw Sapper template and adding the postcss plugin in Rollup config (both client and server) is enough for importing `.scss` or `.less` from a `.svelte` file. Build up from there. And be sure to add plugins and config options **one by one**, and test each one as you add them. This way you'll know immediately where an error comes from, and won't have to jump through hoops, hunting several problems and the interactions between them at once!

Comment: @rixo Doing it right now, thanks for the advice!